# Find record with relationship between two rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to find some records in between 2 record in relate table. I can't modify the table because it is SAP's table.

Example:
Table A

```
DocEntry   LineSeq   AftLine  lineText
1          0         -1       text-before-item        
1          0         1        text-item 1-1
1          1         1        text-item 1-2
1          0         2        text-item 2-1
1          1         2        text-item 2-2
1          0         3        text-item 2-3
1          0         4        text-item 2-4
```

Table B

```
DocEntry   LineNum    ItemCode
1          1          item 1
1          2          item 2
1          5          item 3
```

Now, I need to join both table like this:

```
DocEntry   LineSeq   AftLine  LineNum  ItemCode lineText
1          0         -1                         text-before-item
1          0         1        1        item 1   text-item 1-1
1          1         1        1        item 1   text-item 1-2
1          0         2        2        item 2   text-item 2-1
1          1         2        2        item 2   text-item 2-2
1          0         3        2        item 2   text-item 2-3
1          0         4        2        item 2   text-item 2-4
1                             5        item 3
```

How can I join 2 tables using "between rows" parameter? Number is not sequential. So, please don't use LineNum - 1. 
Aftline is always bigger than the correspond line item, but lower than next line item, and sorted by AftLine first, then LineSeq next.

This is what I came up with, but ends up with getting all items below all LineNum

```
SELECT i1.ItemCode, i1.LineNum, AftLineNum, LineText FROM B i1 
FULL OUTER JOIN A i10 on i10.DocEntry = i1.DocEntry 
AND i10.AftLineNum >= i1.LineNum 
AND i10.AftLineNum < (
    SELECT TOP 1 LineNum FROM B WHERE DocEntry = i1.DocEntry 
        AND B.LineNum > i1.LineNum
        ORDER BY LineNum DESC
)
where i1.DocEntry = 1030
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make tables with sample data:

```
DECLARE @A TABLE (DocEntry int, LineSeq int, AftLine int, lineText varchar(255));

INSERT INTO @A (DocEntry, LineSeq, AftLine, lineText) VALUES (1, 0, -1, 'text-before-item');
INSERT INTO @A (DocEntry, LineSeq, AftLine, lineText) VALUES (1, 0, 1 , 'text-item 1-1');
INSERT INTO @A (DocEntry, LineSeq, AftLine, lineText) VALUES (1, 1, 1 , 'text-item 1-2');
INSERT INTO @A (DocEntry, LineSeq, AftLine, lineText) VALUES (1, 0, 2 , 'text-item 2-1');
INSERT INTO @A (DocEntry, LineSeq, AftLine, lineText) VALUES (1, 1, 2 , 'text-item 2-2');
INSERT INTO @A (DocEntry, LineSeq, AftLine, lineText) VALUES (1, 0, 3 , 'text-item 2-3');
INSERT INTO @A (DocEntry, LineSeq, AftLine, lineText) VALUES (1, 0, 4 , 'text-item 2-4');

DECLARE @B TABLE (DocEntry int, LineNum int, ItemCode varchar(255));

INSERT INTO @B (DocEntry, LineNum, ItemCode) VALUES (1, 1, 'item 1');
INSERT INTO @B (DocEntry, LineNum, ItemCode) VALUES (1, 2, 'item 2');
INSERT INTO @B (DocEntry, LineNum, ItemCode) VALUES (1, 5, 'item 3');
```

For each row in table A find suitable row from table B using `OUTER APPLY`.

```
SELECT *
FROM
    @A AS TableA
    OUTER APPLY
    (
        SELECT TOP(1) TableB.LineNum, TableB.ItemCode
        FROM @B AS TableB
        WHERE
            TableB.DocEntry = TableA.DocEntry
            AND TableB.LineNum <= TableA.AftLine
        ORDER BY TableB.LineNum DESC
    ) AS B
ORDER BY DocEntry, AftLine, LineSeq;
```

Result set:

```
DocEntry    LineSeq    AftLine    lineText            LineNum    ItemCode
1           0          -1         text-before-item    NULL       NULL
1           0          1          text-item 1-1       1          item 1
1           1          1          text-item 1-2       1          item 1
1           0          2          text-item 2-1       2          item 2
1           1          2          text-item 2-2       2          item 2
1           0          3          text-item 2-3       2          item 2
1           0          4          text-item 2-4       2          item 2
```

As you can see the non-matching rows from B are not returned here.
Most likely you have some unique ID column in table B, so include it in this intermediate result set and then `UNION` those rows from table B, that have not been mentioned in this intermediate result set.

Without use of `ID` it may look like this:

```
WITH
CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        TableA.DocEntry
        ,TableA.LineSeq
        ,TableA.AftLine
        ,TableA.lineText
        ,B.LineNum
        ,B.ItemCode
    FROM
        @A AS TableA
        OUTER APPLY
        (
            SELECT TOP(1) TableB.LineNum, TableB.ItemCode
            FROM @B AS TableB
            WHERE
                TableB.DocEntry = TableA.DocEntry
                AND TableB.LineNum <= TableA.AftLine
            ORDER BY TableB.LineNum DESC
        ) AS B
)
SELECT
    DocEntry
    ,LineSeq
    ,AftLine
    ,lineText
    ,LineNum
    ,ItemCode
FROM CTE

UNION ALL

SELECT
    TableB.DocEntry
    ,NULL AS LineSeq
    ,NULL AS AftLine
    ,NULL AS lineText
    ,TableB.LineNum
    ,TableB.ItemCode
FROM
    @B AS TableB
    LEFT JOIN CTE ON
        TableB.DocEntry = CTE.DocEntry
        AND TableB.LineNum = CTE.LineNum
WHERE
    CTE.DocEntry IS NULL
    AND CTE.LineNum IS NULL
ORDER BY DocEntry, AftLine, LineSeq;
```

Result set:

```
DocEntry    LineSeq    AftLine    lineText            LineNum    ItemCode
1           NULL       NULL       NULL                5          item 3
1           0          -1         text-before-item    NULL       NULL
1           0          1          text-item 1-1       1          item 1
1           1          1          text-item 1-2       1          item 1
1           0          2          text-item 2-1       2          item 2
1           1          2          text-item 2-2       2          item 2
1           0          3          text-item 2-3       2          item 2
1           0          4          text-item 2-4       2          item 2
```

Comment: Thank you.. I think that will do it. I'll try it in a moment.
Actually, primary key is DocEntry + LineNum, as it is row table from another header table which I usually put as i0, with DocEntry as its ID. Table A above are description line for each row at Table B.

Answer (score 0):

Select the highest lineNum that is below a certain AftLine value:

```
SELECT A.*,(SELECT TOP 1 ItemCode FROM B WHERE B.LineNum < A.AftLine ORDER BY B.LineNum DESC) FROM A
```

The last line has to be taken separately and UNIONed to the result set:

```
UNION 
SELECT (NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, (SELECT TOP 1 ItemCode FROM B ORDER BY B.LineNum DESC) FROM B
```

As always untested, but I guess you can solve small syntax errors for yourself...

Comment: How about other columns? Because we have a lot of columns to get at table B. I put 2 columns here only to simplify the main problem. Also, DocEntry is not always 1. There are some thousands distinct docentries. DocEntries is what to link Table A and Table B to same document.